# Working with Web services in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, soap

I'm using SOAP in an iPhone app, and I got this error:

```
<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

This is my code:

```
NSString *soapFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                            "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                            "<soap:Body>\n"
                            "<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                            "<Celsius>%@</Celsius>\n"
                            "</CelsiusToFahrenheit>\n"
                            "</soap:Body>\n"
                            "</soap:Envelope>\n",txt1.text];


    NSURL *locationOfWebService = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"];

    NSLog(@"web url = %@",locationOfWebService);

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:locationOfWebService];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapFormat length]];

    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //the below encoding is used to send data over the net
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapFormat dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: print your soapFormat string and check the value of txt1.text is properly coming over there.

Comment: Now check answer3 its working for me......

Answer (score 1):

just went through the url http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx for location of web service, there i found that in while using SOAP 1.1 soap action was http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit

and not http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit as you have written for your soacp action field. 
This is the exact format for sending request to this particular web service ,

```
POST /webservices/tempconvert.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.w3schools.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit"
```

I believe you are setting wrong value of soap action. because soap action mentioned is different from what you have written. (FYI, soap action is used to identify one particular web service or web method, from a large no of web methods , which are present on same location)

Comment: @mahesh chowdary  Lolz ,its quite hilarious that what you are trying to achieve here,  POINTS.
You could have just said change your soap action to the correct one or  voted my answer UP.... I'm still smiling why you wasted your time for the answer already been given..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It will work

```
NSString *soapFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                            "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                            "<soap:Body>\n"
                            "<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/\">\n"
                            "<Celsius>%@</Celsius>\n"
                            "</CelsiusToFahrenheit>\n"
                            "</soap:Body>\n"
                            "</soap:Envelope>\n",@"30"];


    NSURL *locationOfWebService = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"];

    NSLog(@"web url = %@",locationOfWebService);

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:locationOfWebService];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapFormat length]];

    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //the below encoding is used to send data over the net
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapFormat dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

//Try This One It Returns integer value

```
NSString *soapFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                        "<soap:Body>\n"
                        "<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/\">\n"
                        "<Celsius>%@</Celsius>\n"
                        "</CelsiusToFahrenheit>\n"
                        "</soap:Body>\n"
                        "</soap:Envelope>\n",@"50"];


 NSURL *locationOfWebService = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"];

NSLog(@"web url = %@",locationOfWebService);

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:locationOfWebService];

NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapFormat length]];

[theRequest addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue:@"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
//the below encoding is used to send data over the net
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapFormat dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *data_reply;
NSError *err;

   data_reply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest    returningResponse:&response error:&err];

   NSString *aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data_reply encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"aStr:%@",aStr);
```

O/P:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/"><CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>122</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult></CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

  check this answer it returns 122 integer value.......
```